# mysql - slow query of rows filtered by a subquery which counts occurrences of them in other table

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I want to filter the codes with at least 1 barcode with at least X occurrences in store table.

**tables structure**

table codes (now has 1.000 records):

```
code (PK)

ABC
XYZ
```

table barcodes (now has 6.000 records):

```
barcode (PK)    code

ABC             123
ABC             456
XYZ             789
```

table store (now has 67.000 records):

```
id (PK) barcode

1       123
2       123
3       123
4       789
```

how can I speed up this query?

```
SELECT c.code,
    IFNULL(
        (SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM store s INNER JOIN barcode b ON s.barcode=b.barcode WHERE b.code=c.code GROUP BY a.barcode ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1
    ),0) max
FROM codes c
GROUP BY c.code";
HAVING max>=X
```

with x = 2 the expected result is:

```
code    max

ABC     3
```

because only the code ABC has at least 1 barcode (123) with at least 2 occurrences in store table.

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: Questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query, as well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables

Comment: didn't I do that?